# PHP post array cant be echo

Tags: php, post, foreach

I have code in html:

```
<input type="text" name="product[0][name]" value="name of product 1"/>
<input type="text" name="product[1][name]" value="name of product 2"/>
<input type="text" name="product[2][name]" value="name of product 3"/>
<input type="text" name="product[3][name]" value="name of product 4"/>
```

I try to send this via $_POST.
When im using

```
print_r($_POST['product']);
```

I got list of my products for ex:

```
Array
(
    [product] => Array
        (
            ['201'] => Array
                (
                    ['name'] => J5313 BEŻOWE
                    ['price'] => 14.99
                    ['quantity'] => 1
                    ['size'] => 36
                    ['product_subtotal'] => 14.99
                )

            ['200'] => Array
                (
                    ['name'] => J5313 SZARE
                    ['price'] => 14.99
                    ['quantity'] => 1
                    ['size'] => 37
                    ['product_subtotal'] => 14.99
                )

        )

)
```

Everything is ok, but if i want to echo my array variables i have empty vars!
Its my code:

```
foreach($_POST['product'] as $key => $value){
        echo "product key: $key, product name: ".$value['name']."";
}
```

What php write in document:

```
product key: 0, product name:
product key: 1, product name:
product key: 2, product name:
product key: 3, product name:
```

$key variable is not empty but $value is empty!
I try to change name of $value var but its not solve my problem.
Any one knows what i must to to?

Comment: The keys 0, 1, 2 and 3 don't match the earlier array dump; your code looks okay though

Comment: Add `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` to the top of your script to see if any indices of your array are missing.

Comment: You can also add `print_r($value);` inside the loop to see where you have gone wrong

Comment: I tried to mimic your `$_POST` array and your loop works on that array. Something's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's unclear, based on your code, why you're experiencing this problem there are a few debugging steps you could take:

**Show all warnings**

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Add those two lines to your script and run it; if there are any obvious issues like missing indices it will echo warnings in your page.

**Add more debugging**

Since your loop can find the keys, you should `var_dump($value);` inside the loop to figure out if perhaps you made a typo (although that would have shown up by showing all warnings.

Comment: Thank you. In html i add ' in names...
product['$var']['$name']

Im using smarty and i didint see it ^^
now i have product[$var][$name] and all works now :)

Comment: @MateuszKudej glad you found the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST['products'] as $value)
        foreach($value as $k => $v)
                echo $k." -> ".$v['name'];
```

Comment: Unlike others I RUN AND VERIFY MY CODE, COPY, PASTE AND RUN, thank you dynamic

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 foreach($_POST['product'] as $key => $value){
     echo "product key: $key, product name: " . $_POST['product'][$key]['name'];
 }
```